# Missing sgen.exe

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sgen.exe

I’m trying to build NopCommerce via the .BAT files that came with the project but I get an error saying I’m missing sgen.exe. I’ve had a look in all the places it should be and done a search on my computer and it is missing.

I have VWD2010, .NET v4.0.30319 and MVC3 and 4 but no sgen.exe.

I’ve tried to build the project within VWD2010 but there are a bunch of web references residing outside the root of the website.

I think I either need to find a copy of sgen.exe and put it in the place that the .BAT file is looking or better would be to be able to publish it from within VWD2010 but I don’t know how to do that. If I right click on the solution I don’t get an option to publish?

Any suggestions?

Comment: **Important Note:** *The best way to run the .NET Framework tools is by using the Visual Studio Command Prompt, which is provided with Visual Studio 2005 and later versions. If you use the Windows Command Prompt, you must navigate to the Program Files directory the tools are contained in; for example: cd %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.1\Bin.*  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9kh6s92(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Thanks Robert, but I’ve managed to build websites for over 15 years with NEVER having to use the command prompt! The last time I used the command prompt was when was during the DOS era and we were not building websites!

Comment: There's a first time for everything.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1302225/102937 for more possible solutions.   You can get sgen.exe from the [Windows SDK.](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11310)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Publish Instructions for NopCommerce V2.50

I was able to work it out manually, and published both the website and admin within VWD.

1, publish the Nop.Web to the root directory of your choice

2, Create a directory inside your newly create folder and call it Administration

3, Publish Nop.Admin to the newly created Administration directory that is inside your root directory.

4, Copy the Plugins directory (\Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins), not the Plugins directory found in the root to the root of you new project.

5 Copy “all files”, dll’s and the rest from the bin directory in the Administration directory to the bin directory in the root of your project and don’t replace the duplicate files, there will be three that reside in the bin of Nop.Admin that don’t in the bin of Nop.Web

And you done.

Cheers,

Mike.