# "sgen.exe" exited with code -532462766

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sgen

Good day,

I am attempting to build my project in Release mode, but keep getting the error as stated in the title. What causes this and how can I prevent or fix it?

The other answers I saw on stackoverflow, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623/sgen-exe-fails-during-build) one, made no sense to me.

[image: sgen fail]

Comment: That's 0xE0434352, usually bad news when a managed exception cannot be handled.  Look in the Output window for a possibly better diagnostic message.  Try it on another machine.

Comment: That's not good news. I haven't got access to another machine.

Comment: Thank you @HansPassant. Your comment led me straight to the answer. Who knew that our friends that built our beloved Visual studio were a little lazy by making a catch-all error generated by the CLR...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I learned that sgen.exe is an XML Serializer Generator Tool. The error also occurred during the build with `Release` configuration.

Probably a dirty fix, but I viewed the output window to determine which project was throwing this error. After finding which project caused this, I immediately opened that project's properties, went to the build tab, and deactivated "Generate serialization assembly"

[image: fix]

Rebuilt my project - it worked.

Comment: Developers should be concerned about Simply/Merely turning off flags just to quickly resolve an error withOut considering the consequences.